# Proving $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is continuous at $x=c$ by $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I would like to prove the function $f:\Bbb R\to[1,+\infty)$ given by $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is continuous at an arbitrary $x=c$ by the Cauchy definition, that is,

$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)$ s. t. $(\forall x\in\Bbb R)\space((|x-c|<\delta)\implies(|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon))$.

I tried to find a suitable $\delta$ by examining $|f(x)-f(c)|$:

$f(c)=\sqrt{c^2+1}$

$\begin{aligned}|\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{c^2+1}|&=\frac{|\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{c^2+1}|\cdot\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1}}\\&=\frac{|x^2-c^2|}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1}}\\&=\frac{|x-c|\cdot|x+c|}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1}}\\&\le\frac{|x-c|\cdot|x+c|}2\\&\le\frac{|x-c|\cdot(|x|+|c|)}2\\&\le\frac{|x-c|\cdot(|x-c|+2|c|)}2\\&<\varepsilon\end{aligned}$

Is so, by letting $t=|x-c|$,

$t^2+2|c|t-2\varepsilon<0$

$t_{1,2}=\frac{-2|c|\pm\sqrt{4|c|^2+8\varepsilon}}2=-|c|\pm\sqrt{c^2+2\varepsilon}$

Since we're looking for $t>0$, I took $t\in(0,-|c|+\sqrt{c^2+2\varepsilon})$.

I think the statement then follows for any $0<\delta\le-|c|+\sqrt{c^2+2\varepsilon}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Well done! It is correct :)

Comment: @APCorreia, thank you very much for verifying!

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad to help.

Comment: at the stage $|x-c||x+c|/2$ just say $|x+c|\le |x-c|+2|c|\le 3|c|$ for $\delta_1=|c|$. So you get $|f(x)-f(c)|\le|x-c|\frac 32|c|\le\epsilon$ for $\delta_2=\frac 2{3|c|}\epsilon$. Now take $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. I feel, you are complicating the ending unnecessarily.

Comment: @zwim, thank you very much for pointing out! I see.